# Perl regular expression to replace string recursively in multiple file groups, like "*.php" "*.html"

Tags: linux, perl, recursion, replace, regexp-replace

The following command is not working, does nothing:

```
sudo find /srv/my/directory -type f -iname '*.htm*' -iname '*.old1' -iname '*.php' | sudo xargs -iX sudo perl -p -i -e 's|\<\?php.*123456.*123456.*\?\>\r?\n\<\?php|<?php|g' 'X'
```

It does not replace anything in the files.

What is wrong?

**SOLUTION:**

```
sudo find /srv/my/directory -type f -iname '*.htm*' -or -iname '*.old1' -or -iname '*.php' | sudo xargs -iX sudo perl -0777 -p -i -e 's|\<\?php.*123456.*123456.*\?\>\r?\n\<\?php|<?php|g' 'X'
```

**SOLUTION 2 (extends capability for multiple situations in regexp):**

```
sudo find /srv/my/directory -type f -iname '*.htm*' -or -iname '*.old1' -or -iname '*.php' | sudo xargs -iX sudo perl -0777 -p -i -e 's@\<\?php.*123456.*123456.*\?\>(\r?\n|\#\!.*)\<\?php@<?php@gs' 'X'
```

Comment: Can you describe the expected behavior in more detail? Maybe providing an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. When specifying several conditions to `find`, they are by default connected by an implicit `-and`. No file can match `-iname '*.old1' -and -iname '*.php'`. You must specify `-or` explicitly.
2. Unless told otherwise, `perl -p` reads the file line by line, so it can't match `\n<`. Use `-0777` to read the whole file instead of processing it line by line.

```
sudo find /srv/my/directory -type f \
    -iname '*.htm*' -or -iname '*.old1' -or -iname '*.php' \
    | sudo xargs -iX sudo perl -0777 -p -i \
        -e 's/<\?php.*123456.*123456.*\?>\r?\n<\?php/<?php/g' 'X'
```

BTW, you don't need to backslash `<` and `>` in Perl regexes.

Comment: It seems `sudo find /srv/my/directory -type f -iname '*.htm*' -or -iname '*.old1' -or -iname '*.php' | sudo xargs -iX sudo perl -0777 -p -i -e 's|\<\?php.*123456.*123456.*\?\>\r?\n\<\?php|<?php|g' 'X'` solved the problem, replaces correctly. Thanks for your help! Selecting as solution.

Comment: I tried to extend the functionality to handle other cases, but this regexp is not matching: `sudo find /srv/my/directory -type f -iname '*.htm*' -or -iname '*.old1' -or -iname '*.php' | sudo xargs -iX sudo perl -0777 -p -i -e 's|\<\?php.*123456.*123456.*\?\>(\r?\n|\#\!.*)\<\?php|<?php|gs' 'X'`. The regexp is working, tested in online regexp tester, but under Debian/bash I get error like "Unmatched ( in regex; ... xargs: sudo: exited with status 255; aborting"  Do you have idea, what is wrong with the regexp?

Comment: The `|` after `\n` is interpreted as the substitution delimiter. Use a different character (note that I used the standard slash).

Comment: WORKS: `sudo find /srv/my/directory -type f -iname '*.htm*' -or -iname '*.old1' -or -iname '*.php' | sudo xargs -iX sudo perl -0777 -p -i -e 's@\<\?php.*123456.*123456.*\?\>(\r?\n|\#\!.*)\<\?php@<?php@gs' 'X'`